# Float listview over other views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

what i want to achieve is a floating listview above other views(like floating action button)

Is it even possible (something like spinner view which pops up over other views)
If yes how do i implement it?

Comment: Where have you reached with this? Have you seen my answer?

Comment: yes it did solve my problem partially .. but i am still not able achieve what i want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either [`PopupWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) or [`DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), depending on your requirements.

Alternatively, you could also use [`FrameLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) to achieve the same effect. The first child in the `FrameLayout` (presumably your `ListView`) would be the one displayed on top of the others.

Comment: can you please explain how do i use frame layout?/

Comment: The first child in a `RelativeLayout` is displayed on top of the others.